# Is it 'by' or some other preposition in- 'The internet is also a platform by which online tutoring is made possible'

Tags: grammar

Is it 'by' or 'for' or 'through' or 'on' the preposition in the following-

> 'The internet is also a platform **by** which online tutoring is made possible'

Answer (score 2):

Several prepositions would be acceptable here, including **by, on, via** and **through**.

But **for** doesn't work because the sense here is of the means that makes online tutoring possible rather than its purpose.